# How to access public address of smart contract from js?

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, truffle

I have a public address of owner of

```
address public owner;
```

I want to acess it inside a js function. I tried to call it from the instance of the deployed contract but it shows something like

```
 ƒ () {
       var instance = this;
       var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
       var tx_params = {};
       var last_arg = args[args.length - 1];

       // It's only tx_params …
```

in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your contract name is `Cat` and you have `address public owner;` line inside it.

Here is the code that you can use in `$ truffle console` terminal after you deploy the contract:

```
c = Cat.at("put Cat contract address here")
c.owner.call()
```

That's all.